# Django/Python - Unwanted caching of instances in views.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I'm having an issue with a page running on Django 2.1. My issue is that when a function is called from views.py to populate a template, an instance of a class seems to be cached. Every subsequent call to that function/every refresh of that page shows old data from the previous time that page/function was called.

The code in question:

**projectroot/myapp/templates/myapp/bar.html**

```
#this is bar.html
{{ MyTable.DataColumns }}
<br>
{{ MyTable.DataRows }}
```

**projectroot/myapp/views.py**

```
#this is a relevant snippet from views.py
#There isn't anything outside of the functions, 
#with imports being the exception to this rule

import myownpackage.DataTable import DataTable

def list_page(request):
    template = 'foo/bar.html'

    connection = a_connection_here
    query_results = connection.get_query_results(sql_query_here)
    list_of_rows = [x for x in query_results]
    dt = DataTable()
    dt.DataColumns = [list_of_columns_here]
    for each_row in list_of_rows:
        dt.add(each_row)

    return_dict = {"MyTable": dt}

    return render(request, template, return_dict)
```

**projectroot/myownpackage/DataTable.py**

```
class DataTable:

    DataColumns = []
    DataRows = []

    def add(self, data_row):
        if len(self.DataColumns) != len(data_row):
            raise IndexError("Target column count does not match DataTable's DataColumn count.")
        else:
            self.DataRows.append(data_row)

    def remove(self, index):
        self.DataRows.remove(index)
```

The first time this page is loaded, foo/bar.html appears to be just what I want. I can see the columns printed to the page, and the few rows in that table.
The problem is visible if you refresh the page. It's as if **dt** is being cached after the function has returned the render().

When you refresh the page, you'll see the columns, and the rows from the first request duplicated! If we refresh a third time, we'll see a third set of those same rows! This appending of the DataTable goes on for as many times as you refresh. Clearly, **dt** is being stored outside of this function after being instantiated within the function, and I'm not sure why, or how, this is happening.

NOTE: Only the rows are being added over and over again. The columns remain the same. This is because the columns are being *set* on the table, while the rows are being *added*.

*Things I've tried:*

After **dt** is assigned to that return_dict, I've tried **dt = None** and **del dt**. Neither of these worked, and the same results were shown when refreshing the page.

**My questions to Stack Overflow:**

Why isn't the instance of DataTable called **dt** being thrown away after the function returns?

If this (for whatever the reason may be) is normal, what can I do to destroy that instance of DataTable when I'm done with it?

Comment: Please show `DataTable`, or say which package it comes from.

Comment: @Alasdair I've added the code behind DataTable

Comment: @Alasdair good call, the DataTable class was the culprit the whole time!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. As soon as I saw `self.DataRows.append(data_row)` I thought the problem was probably on the `DataTable` class.

Comment: @Alasdair The silly thing is, I had those in the __init__ to begin with, and I can't remember why I had decided to pull them out!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, the issue was that the DataRows were static in the DataTable class. That class should look like this:

```
class DataTable:

    def __init__(self):
        self.DataColumns = []
        self.DataRows = []
```